# ImageMagick mogrify/convert performance slow when over 1120 pixels on resize

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I am using IM to resize an image, like this;

```
mogrify -path . \
        -format 1120.jpg \
        -filter Triangle \
        -define filter:support=2 \
        -scale 1120 \
        -unsharp 0.25x0.08+8.3+0.045 \
        -dither None \
        -posterize 136 \
        -quality 82 \
        -define jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off \
        -define png:compression-filter=5 \
        -define png:compression-level=9 \
        -define png:compression-strategy=1 \
        -define png:exclude-chunk=all \
        -interlace none  \
        -colorspace sRGB \
        0c7c93160ef416ed39ed7600b17a017b.jpg
```

Works really good, and just takes a couple of seconds. But if I increase the size of the output file by 1 pixel, from 1120 to 1121 it takes about 2 minutes to complete.

```
mogrify -path . \
        -format 1121.jpg \
        -filter Triangle \
        -define filter:support=2 \
        -scale 1121 \
        -unsharp 0.25x0.08+8.3+0.045 \
        -dither None \
        -posterize 136 \
        -quality 82 \
        -define jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off \
        -define png:compression-filter=5 \
        -define png:compression-level=9 \
        -define png:compression-strategy=1 \
        -define png:exclude-chunk=all \
        -interlace none  \
        -colorspace sRGB \
        0c7c93160ef416ed39ed7600b17a017b.jpg
```

I do not understand why that should be.

I did read somewhere that -resize (and -thumbnail) increase the image internally to 5 times what the final output will be, in order to do some operations on it. (5x1120)^2 is quite close to 32,000,000 which I think is some kind of magic number in computers. Anyway, I don't really know why.

Can anyone suggest an alternative way of resizing that does not have this draw back.

Comment: Huh? Why are you using `mogrify` for a single image? Why are you setting `PNG` compression parameters when you are saving as a JPEG not PNG? How can you use `-format` without a parameter? What are the dimensions of the original image?

Comment: Hi Mark Setchell, You can use mogrify for a single image, mogrify is not exactly the same as convert. The -format switch does have a paramter 1120.jpg, that means if my filename is abc.png, then the output file will be abc.1120.jpg. The original image is 1901x1901 pixels in size and in this particular case is a jpg.

Comment: There are a lot of options, I will try to remove them one at a time and see if it makes a difference.